# feature selection for time series data like stock market

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, feature-extraction, feature-selection

i am new to data mining,i just want to know which feature selection is easy and best for time series data.
as my project is share market prediction...these are the following parameters available and i have to select best 5 features for constructing my model.can anyone help me which one to use and how to do it..
Features available are
symbol,series,date,prev close,open price,high price,low price,last price,close price,average price,total traded quantity,turnover in lacs, deliverable qty,% deliv qty to to traded qty

you can see those features in this link

[click on it to see the data in nse website to know how data represents](http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm)

Comment: So... you want to predict the stock market? Except you don't know how to do it, and you think someone on Stack Overflow does, and will share the secret with you? I suggest you read the guidelines on what constitutes an appropriate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will not do your home work to select the **features(attributes)** but I can help you so that you can also select features:-
You can use [Minimum-redundancy-maximum-relevance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection#Minimum-redundancy-maximum-relevance_.28mRMR.29_feature_selection).
Do by choosing that features which are less repeating and giving giving high co-relation with output.You must google for more information about **mRMR** algorithm.

Comment: thanks for responding,i done it using ReliefF feature selection technique,it is working fine..

Comment: can you tell me how rbf kernel function works in svm by taking 3 features/parameters as example.

Comment: @user2792746 sorry, not in my knowledge!!